# How do I count with input, in Unity?

Tags: unity

How do I count from 1 to 10? I want to count upwards to 10 when I press C, and count down to 0, when I'm not.

```
void Upload() 
{
    int ten;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))
    {
        // count from 0 to 10. 1 2 3 4....
        Debug.Log (" + " + ten);
    }
    else 
    {
        // count from 10 to 0. 10 9 8 7....
        Debug.Log (" - " + ten);
    }
}
```

Comment: count from 0 to 10 when i press C. else stay at 0 or count from higher number to 0.

Comment: One rarely counts for counting, what do you want to actually happen? Something after 10 seconds, something each second for 10 seconds?

Comment: Please use the edit feature below the question to improve it.

Comment: Wait, do you mean to say *count in seconds while I am pressing C down* or *count up every time I press C*? I am still confused why you would specifically say "in seconds".

Comment: (I'm happy to make the edits once they are confirmed corrections, but it might mean I have to change my answer)

Answer (score 0):

There are only some minor basic problems with your code. I would advise following the base scripting tutorials, on the Unity website. They will provide you with a suitable base understanding of both general programming and programming with Unity, so you can comfortably do the little things.

---

#### Any variable creates inside of a method will be lost as soon as the method completes.

You've declared `ten` during the `Upload` method. As a result, it is disposed of when `Upload` completes.

Simply declare `ten` as a variable of the actual *class*, and any value you set will persist past the `Upload` method.

#### `Input.GetKey` works like "rapid fire", and input should generally come from an `Update` method.

You're using `Input.GetKey` to check for input. This *works*, but it only checks that the key is *being pressed*. Your input updates during the `Update` method, which runs many, many times *every* second; as a result, `GetKey` will return `true` for many frames in a row, even if the user attempts to input the key *once*.

For situations where you require a distinct action every time the user *presses* the button, instead of while the user *holds* the button, use `Input.GetKeyUp` and `Input.GetKeyDown`. Of course, both of these flags return `false` outside of the `Update` method, as they are reset during the same frame as they are first raised. *Ideally, you should get input during your `Update` method*.

#### Counting

Counting, itself, is easy. Add to `ten` when you want the number to go up, subtract from `ten` when you want it to go down. At an introductory level, you would probably write `ten = ten + 1` and `ten = ten - 1`, but there is an easier way.

An easy shorthand version is to use the operators `++` and `--`, which automatically add and subtract by 1. `ten ++` will increase the value of `ten` by 1, and vice versa. Want to count by more than 1? The `+=` and `-=` operators take care of greater numbers. `ten -= 5`, for example, will automatically subtract the value of `ten` by 5.

#### `Update` will count so quickly that you *won't notice*

You probably want the user to be able to *see* the number counting up and down, as I have mentioned in addressing the use of `Input.GetKey`. Given that counting down is the default action, `Update` will count back to 0 so quickly that you probably will not notice. It will appear as if `ten` drops to 0 almost *immediately*.

We can use the `Time` class to account for time, and apply a *timed* countdown, instead of an immediate countdown. This will probably be the most complicated part of the script, but it is all still fairly standard.

There are many ways you might set up a timer. For this purpose, we are counting between `Update` methods, so I will provide an example of how you might use `Time.deltaTime`.

`Time.deltaTime` gives us the time between the two most recent `Update` methods, in seconds. *From* the `Update` method, it is very reliable.

---

Note that you probably may want to include *holding* the key as an event that *prevents* counting down. As such, I ensure that the additional `GetKey` events are not firing, before moving to the count down. *If this is not* what you want, you can simply replace `else if(!(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode)))` with `else`.

```
<summary>Our counter</summary>
int ten = 0;
<summary>Time between each count down, in seconds</summary>
public float countDownTimer;
<summary>Current count down timer</summary>
float countDown = countDownTimer;

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
    {
        // If the user just pressed C, count up.
        ten++;

        if(ten > 10)
        {
            ten = 10;
        }

        // Reset the countdown.
        countDown = countDownTimer;

        Debug.Log("+ : " + ten);
    }
    else if(!(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode)))
    {
        // If the user is not pressing C,
        // Apply countdown to our timer.
        countDown -= Time.deltaTime;

        // If our timer reaches 0, we have been counting down 
        // for long enough to apply subtraction.
        if(countDown <= 0f)
        {
            // Count down and reset countdown timer
            countDown = countDownTimer;
            ten --;

            if(ten < 0)
            {
                ten = 0;
            }

            Debug.Log("- : " + ten);
        }
    }
}
```